# Spring Layout not resizing correctly

Tags: java, swing, springlayout

I am new to the spring layout in Java GUI building, but it seemed that using spring layout was the only way to go if I wanted to layout my GUI the way I wanted.

The problem I am having, is that one of the panels of my GUI expands about a pixel or 2 when I set resizable to false on my `JFrame`. But when I set resizeable to true, everything lines up perfectly the way I want. I know 1 or 2 pixels isn't off by much, but it's enough to make my GUI look weird because some of the text boxes are stretched 1 or 2 pixels larger then the others. Here is the code for my spring layout:

```
    pnlTop.setLayout(layout);

    lblClosetLoc.setText("Closet location:");
    lblPhone1.setText("Phone 1:");
    lblJackPaired.setText("Jack paired:");
    lblPhone2.setText("Phone 2:");
    lblCubicle.setText("Cubicle:");
    lblJackType.setText("Jack type:");
    lblName.setText("Name:");
    lblPhoneJack1.setText("Phone jack 1:");
    lblPhoneJack2.setText("Phone jack 2:");
    lblDataJack1.setText("Data jack 1:");
    lblDataJack2.setText("Data jack 2:");
    lblComments.setText("Comments:");

    txtClosetLoc.setEditable(false);
    txtClosetLoc.setText("");
    txtPhone1.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone1.setText("");
    txtJackPaired.setEditable(false);
    txtJackPaired.setText("");
    txtPhone2.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone2.setText("");
    txtCubicle.setEditable(false);
    txtCubicle.setText("");
    txtJackType.setEditable(false);
    txtJackType.setText("");
    txtFname.setEditable(false);
    txtFname.setText("");
    txtLname.setEditable(false);
    txtLname.setText("");
    txtPhoneJack1.setEditable(false);
    txtPhoneJack1.setText("");
    txtPhoneJack2.setEditable(false);
    txtPhoneJack2.setText("");
    txtDataJack1.setEditable(false);
    txtDataJack1.setText("");
    txtDataJack2.setEditable(false);
    txtDataJack2.setText("");
    txtComments.setEditable(false);
    txtComments.setText("");

    pnlTop.add(lblClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(txtClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(lblCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(txtCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackType);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackType);
    pnlTop.add(lblName);
    pnlTop.add(txtFname);
    pnlTop.add(txtLname);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhoneJack1);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhoneJack2);
    pnlTop.add(lblDataJack1);
    pnlTop.add(lblDataJack2);
    pnlTop.add(lblComments);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhoneJack1);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhoneJack2);
    pnlTop.add(txtDataJack1);
    pnlTop.add(txtDataJack2);
    pnlTop.add(txtComments);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblClosetLoc, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblClosetLoc, 1, layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtClosetLoc, 5, layout.EAST, lblClosetLoc);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc, 5, layout.NORTH, pnlTop);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhone1, 0, layout.WEST, lblPhone2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhone1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhone1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhone1, 0, layout.WEST, txtPhone2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhone1, 0, layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblJackPaired, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblJackPaired, 1, layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtJackPaired, 22, layout.EAST, lblJackPaired);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhone2, 0, layout.WEST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhone2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhone2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhone2, 0, layout.WEST, txtJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhone2, 0, layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblCubicle, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblCubicle, 1, layout.NORTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtCubicle, 47, layout.EAST, lblCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtCubicle, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblJackType, 83, layout.EAST, txtCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblJackType, 1, layout.NORTH, txtJackType);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtJackType, 0, layout.WEST, txtDataJack1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtJackType, 0, layout.NORTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblName, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblName, 1, layout.NORTH, txtFname);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtFname, 56, layout.EAST, lblName);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtFname, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtLname, 5, layout.EAST, txtFname);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtLname, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack1, 0, layout.WEST, txtFname);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack1, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtFname);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack2, 0, layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack2, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtPhoneJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtComments, 0, layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtComments, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtPhoneJack2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtDataJack1, 0, layout.WEST, txtDataJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtDataJack1, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtLname);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhoneJack1, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhoneJack1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtDataJack2, 5, layout.EAST, lblDataJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtDataJack2, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtDataJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhoneJack2, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhoneJack2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblDataJack1, 0, layout.WEST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblDataJack1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtDataJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblDataJack2, 0, layout.WEST, lblDataJack1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblDataJack2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtDataJack2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblComments, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblComments, 1, layout.NORTH, txtComments);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.EAST, pnlTop, 5, layout.EAST, txtDataJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.SOUTH, pnlTop, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtComments);
```

**SSCCE :**

Startup class:

```
public class test1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MainFrame mFrame = new MainFrame();

                mFrame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Main Frame:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

public MainFrame() {
    setupFrame();
}

private void setupFrame() {
    SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();

    pnlMainCenter.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlMainCenter, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    //Top part of the main panel 
    //Information to be displayed
    pnlTop.setLayout(layout);

    lblClosetLoc.setText("Closet location:");
    lblPhone1.setText("Phone 1:");
    lblJackPaired.setText("Jack paired:");
    lblPhone2.setText("Phone 2:");
    lblCubicle.setText("Cubicle:");
    lblJackType.setText("Jack type:");
    lblName.setText("Name:");
    lblPhoneJack1.setText("Phone jack 1:");
    lblPhoneJack2.setText("Phone jack 2:");
    lblDataJack1.setText("Data jack 1:");
    lblDataJack2.setText("Data jack 2:");
    lblComments.setText("Comments:");

    txtClosetLoc.setEditable(false);
    txtClosetLoc.setText("");
    txtPhone1.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone1.setText("");
    txtJackPaired.setEditable(false);
    txtJackPaired.setText("");
    txtPhone2.setEditable(false);
    txtPhone2.setText("");
    txtCubicle.setEditable(false);
    txtCubicle.setText("");
    txtJackType.setEditable(false);
    txtJackType.setText("");
    txtFname.setEditable(false);
    txtFname.setText("");
    txtLname.setEditable(false);
    txtLname.setText("");
    txtPhoneJack1.setEditable(false);
    txtPhoneJack1.setText("");
    txtPhoneJack2.setEditable(false);
    txtPhoneJack2.setText("");
    txtDataJack1.setEditable(false);
    txtDataJack1.setText("");
    txtDataJack2.setEditable(false);
    txtDataJack2.setText("");
    txtComments.setEditable(false);
    txtComments.setText("");

    pnlTop.add(lblClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(txtClosetLoc);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone1);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackPaired);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhone2);
    pnlTop.add(lblCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(txtCubicle);
    pnlTop.add(lblJackType);
    pnlTop.add(txtJackType);
    pnlTop.add(lblName);
    pnlTop.add(txtFname);
    pnlTop.add(txtLname);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhoneJack1);
    pnlTop.add(lblPhoneJack2);
    pnlTop.add(lblDataJack1);
    pnlTop.add(lblDataJack2);
    pnlTop.add(lblComments);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhoneJack1);
    pnlTop.add(txtPhoneJack2);
    pnlTop.add(txtDataJack1);
    pnlTop.add(txtDataJack2);
    pnlTop.add(txtComments);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblClosetLoc, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblClosetLoc, 1, layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtClosetLoc, 5, layout.EAST, lblClosetLoc);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc, 5, layout.NORTH, pnlTop);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhone1, 0, layout.WEST, lblPhone2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhone1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhone1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhone1, 0, layout.WEST, txtPhone2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhone1, 0, layout.NORTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblJackPaired, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblJackPaired, 1, layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtJackPaired, 22, layout.EAST, lblJackPaired);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtClosetLoc);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhone2, 0, layout.WEST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhone2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhone2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhone2, 0, layout.WEST, txtJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhone2, 0, layout.NORTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblCubicle, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblCubicle, 1, layout.NORTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtCubicle, 47, layout.EAST, lblCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtCubicle, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtJackPaired);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblJackType, 83, layout.EAST, txtCubicle);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblJackType, 1, layout.NORTH, txtJackType);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtJackType, 0, layout.WEST, txtDataJack1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtJackType, 0, layout.NORTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblName, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblName, 1, layout.NORTH, txtFname);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtFname, 56, layout.EAST, lblName);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtFname, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtLname, 5, layout.EAST, txtFname);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtLname, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtCubicle);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack1, 0, layout.WEST, txtFname);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack1, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtFname);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack2, 0, layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack2, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtPhoneJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtComments, 0, layout.WEST, txtPhoneJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtComments, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtPhoneJack2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtDataJack1, 0, layout.WEST, txtDataJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtDataJack1, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtLname);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhoneJack1, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhoneJack1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, txtDataJack2, 5, layout.EAST, lblDataJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, txtDataJack2, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtDataJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblPhoneJack2, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblPhoneJack2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtPhoneJack2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblDataJack1, 0, layout.WEST, lblJackType);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblDataJack1, 1, layout.NORTH, txtDataJack1);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblDataJack2, 0, layout.WEST, lblDataJack1);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblDataJack2, 1, layout.NORTH, txtDataJack2);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblComments, 5, layout.WEST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblComments, 1, layout.NORTH, txtComments);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.EAST, pnlTop, 5, layout.EAST, txtDataJack2);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.SOUTH, pnlTop, 5, layout.SOUTH, txtComments);
    //end top part

    //Middle part of the main panel
    //Buttons and options
    pnlMid.setLayout(layout);

    lblRecords.setText("0/MaxRecords");
    lblRecords.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    lblRecords.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(82, 20));

    btnSearch.setText("Search");
    btnSearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 22));
    btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    btnEditSave.setText("Edit");
    btnEditSave.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(75, 22));
    btnEditSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    btnPrevRecord.setText("<<");
    btnPrevRecord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 22));
    btnPrevRecord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });
    btnNextRecord.setText(">>");
    btnNextRecord.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 22));
    btnNextRecord.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        }
    });

    pnlMid.add(btnSearch);
    pnlMid.add(btnEditSave);
    pnlMid.add(btnPrevRecord);
    pnlMid.add(btnNextRecord);
    pnlMid.add(lblRecords);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, lblRecords, 12, layout.WEST, btnPrevRecord);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, lblRecords, 0, layout.NORTH, pnlMid);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, btnSearch, 5, layout.WEST, pnlMid);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, btnSearch, 5, layout.SOUTH, lblRecords);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.WEST, btnEditSave, 5, layout.EAST, btnSearch);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, btnEditSave, 5, layout.SOUTH, lblRecords);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.EAST, btnNextRecord, -5, layout.EAST, pnlMid);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, btnNextRecord, 5, layout.SOUTH, lblRecords);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.EAST, btnPrevRecord, -5, layout.WEST, btnNextRecord);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.NORTH, btnPrevRecord, 5, layout.SOUTH, lblRecords);

    layout.putConstraint(layout.EAST, pnlMid, 0, layout.EAST, pnlTop);
    layout.putConstraint(layout.SOUTH, pnlMid, 5, layout.SOUTH, btnNextRecord);
    //end middle part

    //add the objects to the panels
    pnlMainCenter.add(pnlTop);
    pnlMainCenter.add(pnlMid);
    //add the panels to the frame
    getContentPane().add(pnlMainCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //set frame properties
    setTitle("Test");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    setLocation(300,300);
    pack();
}

private JPanel pnlMainCenter = new JPanel();
private JPanel pnlMid = new JPanel();
private JPanel pnlTop = new JPanel();
private JLabel lblClosetLoc = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblPhone1 = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblJackPaired = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblPhone2 = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblCubicle = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblJackType = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblName = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblPhoneJack1 = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblPhoneJack2 = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblDataJack1 = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblDataJack2 = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblComments = new JLabel();
private JLabel lblRecords = new JLabel();
private JTextField txtClosetLoc = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField txtPhone1 = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField txtJackPaired = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField txtPhone2 = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField txtCubicle = new JTextField(10);
private JTextField txtJackType = new JTextField(5);
private JTextField txtFname = new JTextField(9);
private JTextField txtLname = new JTextField(9);
private JTextField txtPhoneJack1 = new JTextField(6);
private JTextField txtPhoneJack2 = new JTextField(6);
private JTextField txtDataJack1 = new JTextField(6);
private JTextField txtDataJack2 = new JTextField(6);
private JTextField txtComments = new JTextField(15);
private JButton btnSearch = new JButton();
private JButton btnEditSave = new JButton();
private JButton btnPrevRecord = new JButton();
private JButton btnNextRecord = new JButton();
}
```

Comment: yes, the very last thing after i attach the panel to the content pane reads this.setResizable(false); this.pack();

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to demonstrate the problem something else could be going wrong

Comment: After creating the SSCCE it seems to work fine, but the actual program is still stretching by 1 or 2 pixels, with the same things running as the new text program. I will still post the SSCCE i created in a moment. Also i just noticed that if i run both programs side by side, the original is stretched a little

Comment: Well then something in your old code is wrong. use your SSCCE as the foundation and add functionality from older version to the new one until you have all functions working (this way you will see which function you add that is giving problems)

Comment: [see my point 2nd.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13032248/714968), no changes, my endless layzness protect me ...